# ¿Por qué este método no es heredado?

Tags: c++

Dado el siguiente código:

```
class Padre
{
  public:
    int func()
    { return 0; }

    int func2()
    { return 0; }
};

class Hija
  : public Padre
{
  public:
    int func(int param)
    { return param; }
};

int main()
{
  Hija clase;

  std::cout << clase.func(); << std::endl; // ERROR
  std::cout << clase.func(5); << std::endl; // OK
  std::cout << clase.func2(); << std::endl; // OK
}
```

¿Por qué razón el método `func` de la clase padre no existe en la clase hija pese a que la herencia es pública, y sin embargo, `func2` sí?

Comment: Debes sobrecargar la función del padre para poder usarla, además, no sé si en C++ pase, pero si tu no poner la función padre exactamente igual como en la función dentro de la clase hija, lo va a tomar como una función diferente, es decir, si en la clase hija hay un parámetro dentro de la función, en la clase padre debe estar el mismo parámetro.

Comment: Ni dices por qué sucede ni tampoco cómo evitarlo. Lo que he puesto es algo perfectamente legal en C++. Tiene sus motivos y sus soluciones y no, no es necesario que la función de la clase hija tenga que tener exactamente los mismos parámetros que la usada en el padre.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Porque, sin querer, estas invocando la característica de `c++` llamada ***Name Hiding***, de la sección § 3.3.10 del estándar actual para `c++`: (traducción libre)

> Name Hiding: Un nombre será *oculatado* por una declaración explicita con el mismo nombre en una región declarativa anidada o en clases derivadas.

Ten en cuenta que hacer esto **es considerado una mala práctica** dado que resulta poco intuitivo y se recomienda evitarlo. Y no se trata de un error -ya que está bien estipulado en el estándar- sino más bien una característica del lenguaje.

La solución correcta sería utilizar nombres diferentes para los métodos.

Pero si no tienes otra opción o simplemente no quieres utilizar nombres diferentes existe otra característica del lenguaje para hacerla visible de forma explícita en la clase derivada.

Se logra utilizando `using`

```
class Hija
  : public Padre
{
  public:
    using Padre::func; // <-- puedes hacerla visible así.

    int func(int param)
    { return param; }
};
```

[Aquí](http://cpp.sh/7sax) puedes ver el programa funcionando tras la corrección.

Nota: Ten en cuentra que esto sucederá incluso si `Hija::func` se declara como `private` ([ver ejemplo](http://cpp.sh/85jrn)).